# How to add heading levels lower than level 9 in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I am working on a report that, due to external requirements, needs a heading level lower than 9. Entering Outline View and clicking the arrow button to reduce the heading level will not let me reduce it below level 9.

I am not looking for ways to add additional levels to automatically numbered section titles e.g. Section 3.2.5.2.4.1.3.1.5 etc. I am looking for a way to reduce the level of a heading so that it appears at a lower level than level 9 headings in the Navigation panel and TOC.

**How can I add a heading level of 10 and beyond in Microsoft Word 2013?**

Edit: Some clarification

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're not the only one who has been looking for this answer. [Answered by: Luc Sanders](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/exceeding-9-heading-levels/46a7af31-a35c-4656-87c1-eec3c2206fb2)

> 9 levels is the maximum, to keep the file readable that is. Here's a
>   thread that suggests a workaround, based on Word 2003 but still
>   applicable to current versions.
>   http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.word.numbering/browse_thread/thread/10cfb9ee4c92dd6c/61ec9b5e1bb47320?hl=en-us
>
> Luc Sanders MVP - PPT

[The link he refers to](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-us#!topic/microsoft.public.word.numbering/EM-57kyS3Ww):

> At least two posters within the past year have asked how to create 18
>   levels of numbering. Working with the STYLEREF field the other day, an
>   answer occurred to me that's laughably easy.
>   Set up the built-in Heading styles in the legal number format 1.1.,
>   1.1.1., etc. and use them for levels 1 through 9. Beyond level 9, use
>   the STYLEREF and LISTNUM fields side by side -- the first to capture
>   the 9 numeric values at the point of insertion, and the second to
>   number levels 10 to 18.
>
> ```
> ( STYLEREF 9 \S }.{ LISTNUM LegalDefault \L 1 \S 1 )
> ( STYLEREF 9 \S }.{ LISTNUM LegalDefault \L 2 )
> ( STYLEREF 9 \S }.{ LISTNUM LegalDefault \L 3 )
> ( STYLEREF 9 \S }.{ LISTNUM LegalDefault \L 4 )
> ( STYLEREF 9 \S }.{ LISTNUM LegalDefault \L 5 )
> ( STYLEREF 9 \S }.{ LISTNUM LegalDefault \L 6 )
> ( STYLEREF 9 \S }.{ LISTNUM LegalDefault \L 7 )
> ( STYLEREF 9 \S }.{ LISTNUM LegalDefault \L 8 )
> ( STYLEREF 9 \S }.{ LISTNUM LegalDefault \L 9 )
>
> . . . gives you . . .
>
> 3.5.7.2.8.9.4.6.3.1.
> 3.5.7.2.8.9.4.6.3.1.1.
> 3.5.7.2.8.9.4.6.3.1.1.1.
> 3.5.7.2.8.9.4.6.3.1.1.1.1.
> 3.5.7.2.8.9.4.6.3.1.1.1.1.1.
> 3.5.7.2.8.9.4.6.3.1.1.1.1.1.1.
> 3.5.7.2.8.9.4.6.3.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.
> 3.5.7.2.8.9.4.6.3.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.
> 3.5.7.2.8.9.4.6.3.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.
> ```

Comment: Hi Bungicasse, thanks for your quality answer :) However, that's not exactly what I'm looking for; see my edit for clarification.